# Writing CSV data programatically puts commas in Excel instead of simply separating in different cells

Tags: c#, .net, csv

Writing CSV data programatically puts commas in Excel instead of simply separating in different cells.

[image]

What is causing it? How do I solve it?

```cs
const string ou = "\"OU=Students,OU=People,DC=dc1,DC=domain,DC=com\"";
using (var writer = new StreamWriter($@"{outputDirectory}\export.csv", false, Encoding.Unicode))
{
    const string header = "firstname,lastname,username,password,ou";
    writer.WriteLine(header);
    writer.Flush();

    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, accounts.Count))
    {
        var line = $"{accounts[i].FirstName},{accounts[i].LastName},{accounts[i].Username},{accounts[i].Password},{ou}";
        writer.WriteLine(line);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: try with `;` separator instead of `,`

Comment: Yeah, the record separator character changes in locales where `,` is used as the decimal separator. Writing CSV is surprisingly hard. Use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)